# <html> height 100% does not include y-overflow content?

Tags: html, css

I have a page with content contained in `<html></html>` - I'm trying to get a sidebar to span all the way down to the bottom of the page, even if there's vertical overflow.

This is working if there's no vertical overflow, but if there is, the sidebar just stops at wherever the bottom of the page was when the page loaded.

If I use chrome dev tools, I can see that all elements - all the way up to `<html>`, have their height limited to however big the window was when it loaded.  Is this normal?  My problem would be solved if I could tell `<html>` to somehow span vertically to include all content, but I don't know if that's the right solution.

I have set the sidebar and all parents to height:100%, including html:

```
html, body, .durandal-wrapper, #shell-row, #sidebar {
    height: 100% !important;
}
```

I've been working on getting this demod in jsfiddle but can't get it working.  here's what it looks like on my end:

[image]

Comment: You set the heights of html and body to 100% and then you ask if it's normal that those heights are the height of the window? You do realise that 100% IS the height of the window, right?

Comment: @MrLister  A little less snark would be nice, meany.  Obviously I thought it meant 100% of the content :(

Comment: The normal behaviour for blocks (in the absence of any CSS) is to be as high as their content. Sorry if I came across as snarky, but that is one of the basics of how HTML works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use css tables to achieve this.

**[FIDDLE1](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/ZfsAT/4/)**  **[FIDDLE2](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/ZfsAT/5/)**

### Markup

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="sideBar">sideBar</div>
    <div class="main">
        Content.
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.container
{
    display: table;
}
.sideBar
{
    display: table-cell;
    background:pink;
    width: 100px;
}
.main
{
    display: table-cell;
    background:yellow;
    overflow:auto;
    vertical-align: top;   
}
```

Comment: never use display: table-* on none table elements, may cause cross browser issues...

Comment: @redaxmedia can you source that comment?

Comment: check out your jsfiddle with latest Firefox and IE^^ ... not working for me. rethink if this is a bad practice.

Comment: hmm I don't have firefox to test on now, but I'm pretty sure that this technique works with all major browsers... I've probably missed something...I'll check this on IE

Comment: well, I checked it with Firefox - still not working. hacking things with "position:absolute" and "display:table-cell" is not the way to write solid CSS, believe me :-)

Comment: Simulating a table works on Firefox, but you also get all the issues that real tables have, such as the problems with `display:absolute`. And you don't get all the features that real tables have, so there really are no benefits over using a real table.

Comment: When i get a chance i'll try to check this on FF. I do remember that there was a cross browser way of doing this. btw, I also knew about faux cols, but 1) you need an image for that 2) they are also considered a hack - albeit a working one

Comment: @RobVious check the updated fiddle - No more position absolute and works cross-browser

Comment: @redaxmedia: The only browsers that don't understand `display: table` are IE7 and older. I'm guessing something else is wrong.

Comment: @BoltClock initially my css was buggy, but it's fixed now

Comment: @MrLister the benefit of using `table-*` display in CSS only is that it can be used responsively only where appropriate, e.g. on large screen desktops (via media queries).

Answer (score 2):

Faux columns is the usual CSS pattern for your issue:
http://line25.com/articles/create-sidebars-of-equal-height-with-faux-columns

Comment: I just tried this but then I need to make whatever content is NOT the sidebar span down to the bottom of the page, which is the same problem.  I want everything right of the sidebar to be white, all the way to the bottom.